# How much raster data can TimeManager handle?

Tags: qgis, animation, timemanager

I have average wind speed data for the UK at 5x5km grids in raster form for every month over 10 years.

I load the first 7 months into timemanager and the animation is fluid without any loading/down time. As soon as I add the 8th raster (tested with different rasters), there's about 50 milliseconds of thinking time where nothing is displayed until the raster loads and displays the layer. I've built pyramids for the rasters but it hasn't helped. If I load a basemap, then there is 'thinking' time between every raster making the whole animation studder.

Has anybody else ran into a similar issue when animating large datasets?

In the end it won't matter as I can still export the stills into a folder and stitch them together in video editing software but it would be nice for the animation to run smoothly in QGIS.

Comment: is your data still in ASCII grids? if so try converting to geotiffs for speed

Comment: Can you share a minimal dataset and the settings needed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @bugmenot123 Here you are: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1sst2hh3x6y7csd/AAC5eQvNM7V-GP6qpwqDqtz8a?dl=0 The rasters are styled with singleband pseudocolor and standard 'blues' ramp

Comment: I loaded all the 11 files directly (used EPSG:25832 because why not) and styled then with "blues" 0 to 20. I get same rendering times for each frame. Which "show frame for" milliseconds do you use? I DO get much slower rendering if the data covers much of the canvas. Using a static raster basemap with QMS gives no slowdown but I guess QGIS' rendering can not keep up with more complex backgrounds.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I'm using 100 ms per frame. It does't seem to help if I zoom into an area of the canvas. Sorry, but what is QMS?